# Installing Groovy

Tags: groovy

Recently I downloaded Groovy-2.3.6 and try to install it on Linux system. I follow the instruction from http://groovy-lang.org/install.html. I set my GROOVY_HOME variable.

```
export GROOVY_HOME=/home/work/Software/groovy-2.3.6
```

Then I set my environment path variable to the Groovy bin folder

```
  export PATH=$PATH:/home/work/Software/groovy-2.3.6/bin
```

The JAVA_HOME variable is already created.

Now when I'm trying to run any command of Groovy, It generate following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groo/tool/GroovyStarter
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter
      at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
      at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.  Program will exit.
```

I was going through some website to solve that problem. I find that if I set wrong path to GROOVY_HOME then it can happen. I can't figure out what should be the right path for that variable. Can anyone help me with this please. 
 Thanks

Comment: +1 for using gvm, but for the error itself: the proper config would as if you could call `$GROOVY_HOME/bin/groovy`.  so check if you have still another/old groovy in your path before `which groovy`.  so you might want to add your groovy home _before_ the old path: `export GROOVY_HOME=/home/...; export PATH=$GROOVY_HOME/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The simplest way to install Groovy on Linux/Mac is with [SDKMAN](http://sdkman.io/). Here's what I suggest:

- undo everything you've already done
- install SDKMAN by running `curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash`
- open a new terminal and install groovy with the command `sdk install groovy 2.3.6`

Going forward you can use SDKMAN to switch between different versions of Groovy (and Gradle, Grails, Griffon, etc.), install new versions, remove old versions, and so on.

Comment: After curl -s get.gvmtool.net | bash, got "-bash: ZSH_VERSION: unbound variable" error. set it to "", export ZSH_VERSION="". Got "-bash: GVM_FORCE_OFFLINE: unbound variable" when running gvm install groovy 2.3.6.

Comment: GVM has been replaced by SDKMAN.

Comment: Weird, I already use `SDKMAN 5.0.0+51` for Groovy and Grails. `sdk ls groovy` shows I installed and using `2.4.7` But `groovy` command gives me this error too `Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter`

Comment: Ok, my error goes away after uninstalling previous versions `sdk uninstall groovy 2.4.3` `sdk uninstall groovy 2.4.4`  `sdk uninstall groovy 2.4.5`  `sdk uninstall groovy 2.4.6`

Comment: I had the same error using SDKMAN, but unlike Guus I didn't have previous versions installed. However, my error went away after simply starting a new terminal. I had also set the version as the default.

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree the GVM solution is likely the correct way to go, I believe the specific issue you were running into was an extension of the bug that prevents you from having a space in the install path (and the GROOVY_HOME variable); You also can't have hyphens or periods in the path.

So, you would need something like:

```
export GROOVY_HOME=/home/work/Software/groovy236
```

This pattern holds true Windows as well.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows ::

1. Download latest version of groovy from http://groovy.codehaus.org/Download
2. unzip tar file (for e.g c:\groovy)
3. set environment variables:
   a] GROOVY_HOME to your groovy directory(for e.g C:\groovy\groovy-2.4.6).
   b] JAVA_HOME to JRE
4. Make sure that both GROOVY_HOME/bin and JAVA_HOME/bin are available in your PATH

Now you can run your groovy code successfully (for e.g groovy hello.groovy)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue recently when using groovy-2.0.8.
I'm not sure whether my groovy-2.0.8 binary was corrupt or whether version 2 introduced something fundamentally different but, when I set groovy-1.8.9 to my path I no longer got the error when attempting to run a groovy script.

I also found the answer above stating that you cannot have "hyphens or periods" as misleading and incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your path by deleting the "\bin" i got rid of that and it worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu-based distros (you appear to be using something unix-y), `sudo apt install groovy`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message and found out after much trial and error, the `GROOVY_HOME` variable was not set correctly.

The `groovy` application relies on the `GROOVY_HOME` path pointing to the correct directory, or else you will see the error above.

I see an answer above that recommends removing periods from the directory name and adding it to the path. This will work but could be done in a cleaner way using a symlink.

Follow the link below or follow my summary:

https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/All%20Books/9781849519366/1/ch01lvl1sec11/Installing+Groovy+on+Linux+and+OS+X

1. Create a symlink named `current` that points to the main groovy directory (e.g. `/usr/share/groovy/groovy-2.1.6`). The symlink could be located in the same directory that holds the groovy-x.y.z directory. This approach has the advantages of avoiding invalid characters in `PATH` and it can be redirected to a new version of groovy after an upgrade. Here is an example that assumes groovy is installed in `/usr/share/groovy/` and groovy version 2.1.6.

   `sudo ln -s /usr/share/groovy/groovy-2.1.6 current`
2. Use the new symlink to define the `GROOVY_HOME` variable in the login script (e.g. `.profile`):

   `export GROOVY_HOME=/usr/share/groovy/current`
3. Add `GROOVY_HOME/bin` to the `PATH` variable in the login script:

   `export PATH=$GROOVY_HOME/bin:$PATH`
4. *NOTE:* It's best to log out and log in before testing to ensure the initialization script sets the environment variables properly

   Test by executing `groovy -v`

I hope this works well for whomever stumbles upon this link.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem in windows os. I finally found this [page](https://6by9.wordpress.com/2011/01/31/why-you-should-never-set-groovy_home/) and thanks to the author I solved my problem. In short, don't set `GROOVY_HOME` env var. Use something else e.g. `GROOVY_DIR` and then set `%GROOVY_DIR%\bin` in `PATH`. Boom! Groovy is working now.

Answer (score 0):

all commands below failed:

```
export GROOVY_HOME='/Library/groovy4012'
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/groovy4012/bin
groovy
groovy -v
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/groovy4012/
groovy -v
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/groovy4012
groovy -v
export PATH=$GROOVY_HOME/bin:$PATH
groovy -v
```

but after this, I tried a different approach

```
cd /Library/groovy4012/bin
./groovysh
```

and worked :)

btw it's funny that nobody can explain how the manual installation on Linux/MacOS should be done properly

Comment: the command below worked, however after opening the terminal again stopped working ;) 
% export PATH="$PATH:/Library/groovy4012/bin"
% groovysh

Comment: on Linux I've just typed: 
export GROOVY_HOME=/home/username/groovy-4.0.8
export PATH=$GROOVY_HOME/bin:$PATH
groovy
groovysh
groovy scriptName

and worked